# Escaping Variable white space

Tags: javascript, html, variables, escaping, whitespace

I got a html table and I'm retrieving the value of a cell with:

```
var orderid = document.getElementById("orderid"+row).innerText;
```

The value of the cell is an orderid for example 10234.
However when I alert the variable it comes with whitespaces in the front of the string and in the back. This causes that a particular query can't compare database entries with the variable as those database entries haven't got the whitespaces. How do I trim this to just the 10234 without the white spaces around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's always a number, you can use [`parseInt(orderid)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). Otherwise, [`orderid.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) (you need IE9+)

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
stringToTrim.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"")
```

Comment: It removed the whitespaces as I can see in the alert, but it still has issues as it is almost centered in the alert box. So the query still can't compare.